# Is there a way to list the contents of different values after counting in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, group-by, count

If multiple customers are living at the same address, in addition to counting the number of customers living at that address, is there a way to list the names of the customers right next to the counted number?

For example...

[image: Please click for sample image]

Thank you!

Comment: Put a sample of your data in a [fiddle](https://sqlfiddle.net), edit your question adding the link, and I'll take a stab at it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, with `group_concat`

```
select
count(*) as number_of_customers,
group_concat(name) as customer_names
from customers where ...
```

Comment: @user14470792 Please be sure to upvote / accept the answer